# How to run Monero-wallet-rpc on windows?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

I downloaded monero-cli for windows, I double clicked monerod, when its synchronised I double clicked monero-wallet-cli, I created wallet, then I clicked monero-wallet-rpc, it gets closed within a second, I tried to use wallet rpc methods using postman but could not get any response, but when I use daemon rpc methods which are on 18081 as per official documentation, it gave me 
a response. What am I doing wrong while accessing wallet-rpc methods?

Comment: You could start with opening a cmd window and than starting the monero-wallet-rpc from there. Than you will se the error message.
Post it here please.

Answer (score 0):

When starting your monero-wallet-rpc you need to specify which wallet file to use along with a password and a port.

run `monero-wallet-rpc -h` to see arguments to start the wallet rpc server.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on an icon, it's likely not set up to pass a port (-p XXXX), which is a required argument. Additionally, either a wallet (--wallet-file XXXX) or wallet directory (--wallet-dir XXXX) is needed. As far as I know, Windows does not need any special things done for just running it, so any Linux based example should work the same on Windows.